# Julia Variable value reset

Tags: function, variables, initialization, julia

I'm just starting in Julia after a strong background in C++. I'm having an issue with my integer variables being reset to what I initialized them as in the beginning of my program.. even though I changed the variable value inside a function. Can anyone explain why this is?

```
num = 0

function getNum()
    num = 1
end

getNum()
num    #this returns 0, not 1
```

This is a problem because I will need to reference that variable in another function.

Comment: Is it because you aren't calling that function?

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num` is in [global scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Global_scope) (note that the same behavior applies in e.g. Python)

If necessary, you could modify it by referencing as a global:

```
function getNum()
   global num = 1
end
```

However, it is worth considering whether there is a more effective way to structure your code. Global variables can be useful in some situations, but they can also make code more difficult to reason about.